Что следует понимать под source (preprocessing) files в ISO/IEC 9899:2024 в пункте 5.2.1.1?
Цитирую стандарт:

The text of the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this document.

Встретил в англоязычном StackOverflow мнение (ссылка затерялась), что стандарт не описывает файлы исходного кода как файлы на диске компьютера. Как тогда на самом деле можно понимать здесь термин source files, когда они всё же содержат текст программы, - это некие подстроки?

Наверное имеется в виду, что файл это набор данных, который можно передать компилятору. Я понмаю, что современное поколение не представляет ничего кроме устройств с произвольным доступом типа дисков, содержащих файловые системы. Но раньше были в ходу и определенным образом организованные устройства последовательного доступа -- магнитные ленты, колоды перфокарт и перфоленты (иногда к устройствы ввода с перфоленты цепляли телетайп и можно было перегнать данные с одного компа на другой (ага, сетей тогда еще не было))

Это ведь и есть определение source file-ов с т.з. стандарта, т.е. то где хранится текст программы, неважно в каком виде это хранение происходит в ОС.
